# Upload de arquivo dando erro abrindo a página pelo celular Android

Tags: php, laravel, upload, file-upload, dropzonejs

O upload ocorre de forma normal abrindo a página pelo Windows. Porém, abrindo pelo celular parece que concluiu pelo frontend mas não envia o arquivo.

Estou utilizando Dropzone e recebo os dados no controller Laravel.

html:

```html
<form action="{{ route('uploadOnlyImage') }}" name="{{ $item->slug }}" class="dropzone upload_only_form" id="{{ $item->slug }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="area-upload">
       <div class="dz-default dz-message"><span>Selecionar imagem</span></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```js
var optionsUploadOnly = {
    maxFilesize: 10,
    acceptedFiles:".png, .jpg, .jpeg",
    maxFile: 2,
    method: "POST",
    url: "/uploadOnlyImage",
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictRemoveFile: "Remover foto",
    success: function (file, response) {
        var imgName = response;
        file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
    },
    error: function (file, response) {
        file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-error");
    }
}

$(`#dropzone`).dropzone( optionsUploadOnly );
```

Php:

```php
public function uploadOnlyImage(Request $request)
{
    $nameFile = null;

    if ($request->hasFile('file') && $request->file('file')->isValid()) {

        $uniqName = uniqid(date('HisYmd'));
        $extension = $request->file->extension();
        $nameFile = "{$uniqName}.{$extension}";

        $originalName = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileName = $request->file->getPathname();


        $path = $request->file('file')->storeAs("public/fotos/geral", $nameFile);

        if($path){
            StoreUploadOnly::create([
                'original_filename' => $originalName,
                'uniqname' => $nameFile,
                'filename' => $fileName,
                'path' => $path
            ]);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido o problema.
Para quem passar por algo semelhante verificar se as configurações no php para upload estão com tamanhos apropriados em php.ini.

As fotos tiradas no celular estavam com resolução muito alta.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-ask).